# How to get history of changes between two changelists for current client (workspace)?

Tags: perforce

We have a Perforce workspace with complex view:

> `//depot/aaa/... //myclient/1/...`
>   `//depot/bbb/... //myclient/2/555/...`
>   `//depot/ccc/... //myclient/300/...`

How (using p4 command line) I can get history of **changes between two specific changelists restricted by the workspace view spec?**

I know how to do this for all depot (with no restriction by workspace):

> `p4 changes //...@1,5 -s submitted`

And I know how to get all changes for specific client:

> `p4 changes //...@myclient -s submitted`

How can I join two these commands?

BTW, If I use key `-c myclient` in `p4 changes` command, it shows only changelist which submited from the client (and not filter by client view like I need):

> `p4 changes -c myclient //...@myclient -s submitted`

Comment: Do you have access to the workspace directly? If you're at the top of the workspace, you can just use `p4 changes ...@1,5 -s submitted`.

Comment: Wow! It works! Why you didn't add this like an answer? Maybe you can clarify for me - what means "..." in this case?

Comment: `...`, here, means all files from here down recursively. Since you're at the root of the client, it means all files on the client. See the [file specification](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/filespecs.html) documentation for event more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to the workspace directly, you can just use

```
p4 changes ...@1,5 -s submitted
```

from the top of the workspace.